# How do I know if the rebuild process works?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Firstly, I have determined fragmentations with this scripts:

```
SELECT
     B.name AS TableName
    ,C.name AS IndexName
    ,C.fill_factor AS IndexFillFactor
    ,D.rows AS RowsCount
    ,A.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
    ,A.page_count
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) A
INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects B
ON 
    A.object_id = B.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.indexes C
ON 
    B.object_id = C.object_id AND A.index_id = C.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions D
ON 
    B.object_id = D.object_id AND A.index_id = D.index_id
WHERE 
    C.index_id > 0
order by
    avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc
```

then i have executed reorganize or rebuild scripts like this:

```
alter index IX_ind1
on          TABLE1
reorganize

alter index IX_ind2
on          TABLE1
rebuild
```

How do I know if the rebuild process works?

Can I see query list about these indexes? How can I compare queries before rebuild and after rebuild?

Comment: You have the name of the index and table in the first query. So just run it again and compare. If you want to limit the output of the first query, either add a where clause or adjust the parameters to [dm_db_index_physical_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql) as needed.

Answer (score 0):

One short and quick fix will be to create a table and store all results from your query into it, along with an additional boolean column `IsBeforeRebuildOfIndexes`.

You can then query and compare if there was an improvement before and after.